# Display Json Data as menu item in android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, menuitem

I'm fetching Json Data like this (both value and keys)

```
new RequestTypes().execute().get();
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(typesresponse);
        JSONObject object2 = object.getJSONObject("types");
       for(int i =0;i<object2.names().length();i++){
           key = object2.names().getString(i);
           value = object2.getString(key);
       }
```

I'm successfully doing it, and I have an menu item drop down list like this:

```
 public View.OnClickListener typedropdownlistener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(PostPaq.this, v);
        //Inflating the Popup using xml file
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.type_menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.show();
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(typemenulistener);
    }
};
```

My question is how can I parse the 'value' and 'key' variables to my menu item XML? Is it even possible, because I want to show the parsed json data as drop down like I'm showing right now with last piece of code, but its predefined, and that's why I want to parse the received json data, so it will not be predefined?

Answer (score 3):

After not receiving any answer and having no research result i done it all by myself and i make it work.Here is solution for this how do i achieved this.I only changed everything inside my click and it happily do inflate how i want!

```
 public View.OnClickListener typedropdownlistener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        popup = new PopupMenu(PostPaq.this,v);
        for(int i =0;i<object2.names().length();i++){
            try {
                key = object2.names().getString(i);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                value = object2.getString(key);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file
            //popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.type_menu, popup.getMenu());
            popup.getMenu().add(key+"-"+value);
        }
        popup.show();
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(typemenulistener);
    }
};
```